# RGB value ontouch function

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-bitmap, android-color

I am trying to get the `rgb` value from an image but I always get a different value even on the same pixel.

I used following code:

```
imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) 
imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {

        int x= (int)event.getX();
        int y= (int)event.getY();
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

        int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
        int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
        int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);

        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", redValue, 
        greenValue, blueValue), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "R= " + redValue + "G= " + greenValue + 
        "B= " + blueValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+x+"\tY "+y,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: In toast add pixel too, so that you can verify which pixel you are touching. There is a high probability you are getting different  pixel on different touch so colors will be different.

Comment: tried but get different result on same color.